# pgfplots - Is there an equivalent to 'cycle list name=color list' for custom lists?

Tags: pgfplots

I defined my own cycle list `mycolor`, which equals the vanilla `color` one except for 2-3 different colors and I added two more items to the cycle.

The manual says on page 176:

> The `cycle list name=color` choice also employs markers whereas `color list` uses only colors.

I was wondering: is `color list` baked into pgfplots, meaning `color list` was defined line by line? I would like to use `mycolor` in an analogical way to `color list`, but using `mycolor list` lead to an "unknown list"-type of error.

Comment: Please show us the code that caused problems, that might be it? It shouldn't be a problem to what I think you want. A couple of pages further down from your reference the exact definition of `color list` and `color` are shown.

Comment: May be last part of [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134368/1952) can help you.

Comment: @zeroth Oh... it's on page 178. I didn't see that, my bad. If you like, you could provide your comment as an answer with the note that it's defined by hand and... I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: @henry, hmm, it doesn't really matter to me, in my opinion it might be too localized to be helpful to others, so closing it?

Comment: @zeroth Huh, closing? I think: If it doesn't matter to you, I'll do it myself? Are you ok with that?

Comment: Sure... :) No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent to 'cycle list name=color list' for custom lists?

No, since `color list` was defined as well line by line. See page 178 in the manual, it's in the second blue code snippet.

Hence, a custom list without any markers has to be defined line by line as well.

Comment: Oh, now I understand the question better, I suppose you can just add `no markers` to not add the markers from custom lists. Or do it individually with `\addplot+[no markers]`, or is this not preferred?

Comment: This is clearly not preferred since it's quite cumbersome to do that for every `\addplot+`. At least I prefer the preamble-way, it's faster. :) But for customizations on a local level, this works as well of course.

Comment: I meant `no markers` in the `\begin{axis}[no markers]` for the generic case. I would do `\pgfplotsset{my color list/.style={cycle list name=my color,no markers},my color/.style={cycle list name=my color}}` and you're done. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, yes, I suppose that would work as well. :)