# How to use cycle list = black white properly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am not getting the black white cycle list working. All three graphs are solid black lines. I want them to have different dash patterns though!

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=5in,
xlabel={Time},
ylabel={Displacement},
no markers,
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
cycle list name=black white,
]
\addplot+ table [x=time,y=disp_body,col sep=comma]{tables/data_static.csv};
\addplot+ table [x=time,y=disp_spring,col sep=comma]{tables/data_static.csv};
\addplot+ table [x=time,y=disp_tyre,col sep=comma]{tables/data_static.csv};
\addlegendentry{Car body}
\addlegendentry{Spring}
\addlegendentry{Tyre}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Determination of static deflections}
\label{fig_static}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this can help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134368/1952

Comment: I had seen that earlier, but I still can't see what's causing the problem in my file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code (though I wouldn't add standalone plus signs or I would also add `[]`). The reason why they show up static is because the first 5 cycle definitions are with solid lines and with different markers which you turned off. From the manual

[image]

If you shift the cycle list you will see that it is working OK.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
no markers,
cycle list name=black white,
]
\addplot+[] {rand};\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=4}
\addplot+[] {rand};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks! I guess that means I can't use the black white cycle list for more than 2 plots because the 3rd line looks the same as the 2nd.

Comment: @thirteen Yes but you can create your own cycle lists. There are a few examples in the manual so that you can fiddle with dash patterns etc.

Comment: Found a custom cycle list in this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134346/different-marker-shape-for-pgf-tikz which solved my problem.

Comment: @thirteen So that link did helped you afterall :)

Comment: Be fair: @thirteen never claimed it didn't help but only that it did not explain the problem.

Comment: @cfr Come again?

Comment: @thirteen Indeed ;).