# Specifying markers in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following chart...the below code won't build without the data files, but an image follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    legend columns=4,
                    legend entries={{\tiny Random},{\tiny +Cost},{\tiny +FTE},{\tiny ++Cost},{\tiny ++FTE},{\tiny ++Resources}, {\tiny ++Cost$_{tri}$}, {\tiny ++FTE$_{tri}$}, {\tiny ++Resources$_{tri}$}, {\tiny ++Cost$_{LN}$}, {\tiny ++FTE$_{expo}$}, {\tiny ++Resources$_{expo}$}},
                    legend to name=DollarsLegend,
                    mark repeat=20,
                    xlabel = Simulation Day,
                    ylabel = Dollars Committed,
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=260,
                    width=0.9\textwidth,
                    y tick label style={
                      /pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed,
                      fixed zerofill,
                      precision=0,
                      /tikz/.cd
                    },
                    x tick label style={
                      /pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed,
                      fixed zerofill,
                      precision=0,
                     /tikz/.cd
                    },
                    scaled ticks=false,
                    yticklabel={${\$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
                    ]
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=Random, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize Random}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusCost, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize +Cost}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusFTE, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize +FTE}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusCost, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Cost}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusFTE, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++FTE}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusResources, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Resources}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusCostTri, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Cost$_{tri}$}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusFTETri, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++FTE$_{tri}$}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusResourcesTri, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Resources$_{tri}$}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusCostLN, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Cost$_{LN}$}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusFTEExpo, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++FTE$_{expo}$}}
                \addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusResourcesExpo, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Resources$_{expo}$}}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
            \ref{DollarsLegend}
        \caption{Dollar Commitment versus Time}
        \label{DollarCommitment}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Here's the resulting chart

[image: screen capture1]

I need to prepare this for black and white publication, so I need to make sure every series has a marker that is distinguishable without color.  But when I modify my `\addplot` lines to look like this, for example

```
\addplot table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=Random, x=Day, mark=triangle]{DollarCommitment.csv};
```

I get the same chart....as if my mark specification is ignored.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If not duplicate, at least related with http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134368/1952

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add `mark=` (and `line join=round,` too, it is exercise for you) to `\addplot` options not to `table` options.

```
\addplot+[black,line join=round,mark=Mercedes star] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusFTEExpo, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
```

As an alternative, you can also use a `cycle list` (instead of typing all those marks). There are many built-in ones mentioned in the manual, but you can build your own (see the manual), for example:

```
cycle list name=black white,
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    legend columns=4,
                    %legend entries={{\tiny Random},{\tiny +Cost},{\tiny +FTE},{\tiny ++Cost},{\tiny ++FTE},{\tiny ++Resources}, {\tiny ++Cost$_{tri}$}, {\tiny ++FTE$_{tri}$}, {\tiny ++Resources$_{tri}$}, {\tiny ++Cost$_{LN}$}, {\tiny ++FTE$_{expo}$}, {\tiny ++Resources$_{expo}$}},
                    legend to name=DollarsLegend,
                    %mark repeat=20,    %% uncomment in your data
                    xlabel = Simulation Day,
                    ylabel = Dollars Committed,
                    xmin=0,
                    xmax=260,
                    width=0.9\textwidth,
                    y tick label style={
                      /pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed,
                      fixed zerofill,
                      precision=0,
                      /tikz/.cd
                    },
                    x tick label style={
                      /pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed,
                      fixed zerofill,
                      precision=0,
                     /tikz/.cd
                    },
                    scaled ticks=false,
                    yticklabel={${\$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
                    %cycle list name=black white,
                    %every mark/.append style={fill=gray!10}
                    ]
                \addplot+[black,mark=o] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=Random, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize Random}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=x] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusCost, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize +Cost}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=|] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusFTE, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize +FTE}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=square] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusCost, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Cost}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=star] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusFTE, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++FTE}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=10-pointed star] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusResources, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Resources}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=otimes] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusCostTri, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Cost$_{tri}$}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=oplus] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusFTETri, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++FTE$_{tri}$}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=triangle] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusResourcesTri, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Resources$_{tri}$}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=diamond] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusCostLN, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Cost$_{LN}$}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=Mercedes star] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusFTEExpo, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++FTE$_{expo}$}}
                \addplot+[black,mark=pentagon] table[line join=round,col sep=comma, y=PlusPlusResourcesExpo, x=Day]{DollarCommitment.csv};
                \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize ++Resources$_{expo}$}}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
            \ref{DollarsLegend}
        \caption{Dollar Commitment versus Time}
        \label{DollarCommitment}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!  This is the first paper I've written using pgfplots, so I'm slowly climbing the learning curve.  Vastly prefer this to importing picture files though....

Comment: @user1922959 You really did a good job by choosing a proper method for plotting and choosing a proper tool for it. All the best. You are in good company here. :-)