# How to create an array of styles and use it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to create an array of custom defined styles and afterwards use these styles by getting them by index.

**My approach so far, which isn't working:**

1. Defining some styles:

   ```
   \pgfplotsset{
       redline/.style={
           red
       },
       blueline/.style={
           blue
       }
   }
   ```
2. Defining an array with the styles:

   ```
   \def\mystylesarray{
       {redline},
       {blueline}
   }
   ```
3. Using them in a plot:

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}
           \addplot[\mystylesarray[0]] {x};
           \addplot[\mystylesarray[1]] {x^2};
       \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

I also tried the following:

In step 2. I tried `\newcommand` instead of `\def` and using two braces around the array implementation. In step 3. I tried curly braces and normal braces. All sorts of combinations and looking for an answer online didn't bring up a solution.

Your help is appreciated.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
    redline/.style={
        red
    },
    blueline/.style={
        blue
    }
}
\def\mystylesarray{
    {redline},
    {blueline}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[\mystylesarray{0}] {x};
    \addplot[\mystylesarray{1}] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you want `pgfplotscreatecyclelist`

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example if @cmhughes's comment does not answer your question.

Comment: I forgot to say: Welcome to the site :) I'll post a complete example later on demonstrating the `pgfplotscreatecyclelist`; of course, if you're able to construct one yourself that meets your needs, it's perfectly ok to post an answer to your own question!

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for the warm welcome. 
No I don't want a cycle list. I need a collection of styles I can use throughout my pictures and plots. 
@cfr Isn't the example I posted enough? A complete example would only include `usepackage` command and a documentclass...

Comment: @daniatic, what exactly should be the advantage to have an array of styles? I don't see a disadvantage of directly using the style, e.g. `redline` instead of `\mystylesarray[0]`. If you want consistency throughout your document I would suggest creating a `cycle list` or `cycle list`s of your need and combine them with styles for different types of diagrams.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, the advantage would be to have multiple arrays with different style definitions. At compilation I could provide the desired style array and I would not need to change all styles one by one. The actual goal is to have a switch for black&white and color print outs. The styles for b&w-print would be solid, dashed and so forth and for color-print different colors. I could implement different cycle list depending on the bw-color switch, but then I have a problem when I need specific colors of the cycle list in a different order. Or is it possible to access cycle list entries?

Comment: Is this for pgfplots or Tikz?

Comment: @percusse I would like to find a solution for both!

Comment: @daniatic, that should not be a problem. Define all the styles independently and then create some more styles that describe the use-case and in them call the style and/or `cycle list` that fits the current use-case. Create a second set of this styles fitting another use-case. Then you can simply comment or uncomment them. If you want to simplify it further, add the different use-case styles to different files and load the one you want to use by `\input{...}`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for your answer. I just came up with the same solution and was writing a comment... Is it possible to close this question or do I have to delete it?

Comment: @daniatic, we can either close it as "solved in the comments" or you can delete it. As you wish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: Does it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134368/1952