# using cycle list to use a predefined set of markers on a 2D scatter plot

Tags: pgfplots

I have to create a bunch of scatter plots and I would like to avoid having to manually redefine the markers for all of the plots each time I decide that it does not look good enough... anyways, I see how to do this with the line included [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134346/different-marker-shape-for-pgf-tikz/134368), but I cannot figure it out when I want to use 
`\addplot[only marks]`

here is the MWE of the manual way

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
    \addplot[blue, only marks,mark=*] 
    coordinates{(1,2)(2,3)};
    \addplot[red, only marks,mark=square*]
    coordinates{(1.2,2.2)(2.2,3.2)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

OR... is there a way to somehow turn off the line that goes through the marker and use 
`\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{}`

Thanks!

Comment: Your MWE isn't a complete MWE. It lacks `\documentclass`, the used packages and `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Skillmon fine for me but I don't understand the question.

Comment: @percusse, so instead of the MWE, I want to be able to define a single list of markers at the start of my code that defines all of the markers in the rest of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\addplot+[only marks]`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[]
  \addplot+[only marks] 
  coordinates{(1,2)(2,3)};
  \addplot+[only marks]
  coordinates{(1.2,2.2)(2.2,3.2)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `+` makes `\addplot` use all the default options (cycling through the markers) plus the options you specify (`only marks`).

To further shorten that, if you want to use the option `only marks` on each `\addplot` inside a `tikzpicture` you can use:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[only marks]
  \begin{axis}[]
  \addplot
  coordinates{(1,2)(2,3)};
  \addplot
  coordinates{(1.2,2.2)(2.2,3.2)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can also give this as an option to `axis` (`\begin{axis}[only marks]`).

To change the cycle list used you can use the option `cycle list name=<name>` in the options of `axis`. Predefined cycle list are listed in the corresponding section of the package documentation.

You can also provide your own cycle list:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[only marks,
      cycle list={
        {blue,mark=*},
        {red,mark=square*,mark options={fill=green}},
        {mark=o},
        {yellow,mark=+},
      }
    ]
  \addplot
  coordinates{(1,2)(2,3)};
  \addplot
  coordinates{(1.2,2.2)(2.2,3.2)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And lastly: You can save this cycle list with a name to reuse it with the `cycle list name` key:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{foo}{
        {blue,mark=*},
        {red,mark=square*,mark options={fill=green}},
        {mark=o},
        {yellow,mark=+},
      }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \begin{axis}[only marks,
      cycle list name=foo
    ]
  \addplot
  coordinates{(1,2)(2,3)};
  \addplot
  coordinates{(1.2,2.2)(2.2,3.2)};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could as well specify the `only marks` key in each of the elements of that `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist` (or just in some).